# Passing displayed ViewModel data along with textbox data to Controller asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, binding, controller, viewmodel

ViewModel class

```
public class CreateMRViewModel
{
    public Decimal? Freight { get; set; }
    public IList<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }
}

public class OrderLine
{
    public string LineNumber { get; set; }
    public string VendorPartNumber { get; set; }
    public long? Quantity { get; set; }
    public string UOM { get; set; }
    public decimal PricePerUom { get; set; }
    public long? ReturnQuantity { get; set; }
    public long? QuantityAvaiToReturn { get; set; }
}
```

My View

```
@model CreateMRViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
<fieldset>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Line Number</th>
            <th>Part Number</th>
            <th>UOM</th>
            <th>PricePerUom</th>
            <th>Available Qty</th>
            <th>Return Qty</th>
        </tr>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.OrderLines.Count; i++)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.OrderLines[i].LineNumber)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.OrderLines[i].VendorPartNumber)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.OrderLines[i].UOM)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.OrderLines[i].PricePerUom)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.OrderLines[i].Quantity)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model.OrderLines[i].ReturnQuantity)</td>
        </tr>
        }
    </table>
    <br />
    <div class="display-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => Model.Freight)</div>
    <div class="display-field">@Html.TextBox("Freight", new Int64())</div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <input class="submitForm" type="submit" value="Create Return" />
</fieldset>
}
```

Action Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateMR(CreateMRViewModel mrViewModel)
{
    //some code here
}
```

My problem is: I get the CreateMRViewModel to controller but only textbox values are available for me to use. How can I get the displayed values such as LineNumber or VendorPartNumber for use in controller method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually posting any values for those `Properties` since you're using `DisplayFor()`

If you simply want to just pass it through to the `[HttpPost]` method you're going to need to represent it with a hidden input or make it editable.

```
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.OrderLines[i].VendorPartNumber)
    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.OrderLines[i].VendorPartNumber)
</td>
```